# Cascading Inserts in MySql

Tags: mysql

I have a users table that has a one to one relationship to a user_preferences table (primary foreign key user_id). When a new row is added to the users table (new id added), is there a way to setup the relationship between the users_preferences table so that a row with the new user id is also added to it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Calling this a way to "setup the relationship" isn't quite technically accurate, but you can do this with an `AFTER INSERT` trigger on the user table.  If all of the other columns in user_preferences have appropriate default values defined, and creating a "matching" row is all you need, then:

```
mysql> CREATE TRIGGER user_ai AFTER INSERT ON `user` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO user_preferences (user_id) VALUES (NEW.user_id);
```

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/triggers.html

Triggers that execute more than one statement require you to temporarily change the `DELIMITER` from the normal semicolon to something else, and use an outer `BEGIN` and `END` block.  This also works with a single-statement trigger, but isn't strictly necessary, so the format above will work in this case.

Comment: in case of multiple triggers executing on multiple tables to fill one defined table, taking in mind all default values are set correctly. can you help me with an example.
+1, on your answer :)

Comment: If you have a question that is related to, but not the same as, this one, you should probably post it as a different question, and, you should probably link to this question including an explanation of why your question is not a duplicate.  I suspect, though, that the answer to what I think you might be asking would involve using [`INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.6/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) to leave any existing values there, if the row exists, and insert a new row if it doesn't already exist.

Comment: thanks for your fast response, and as you said, it is better to post a different question :)

Comment: I added this [question](http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/51564/filling-a-table-by-triggering-multiple-tables-on-insert)